# How to tell if a store is open based on repeating, weekly hours?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

I have an iPhone app that displays information for local store's hours and if they are open or not at the current time. I am currently storing the data as follows in a plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>sunday</key>
    <string>11:00-13:00</string>
    <key>monday</key>
    <string>11:00-18:00</string>
    <key>tuesday</key>
    <string>09:00-23:00</string>
    <key>wednesday</key>
    <string>12:00-24:00</string>
    <key>thursday</key>
    <string>13:00-04:00</string>
</dict>
```

As shown, I am using a 24 hour clock. Also, some days stay open until the next day, so closing at 04:00 under Thursday means it actually closes at 4am on Friday.

What is the most effective way of determining if the the selected store is open or closed?

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off storing the times as NSDates rather than strings. Then you would just have do `NSDate *now = [NSDate date]` and say something like: `if (now > openTime && now < close time){store.open = YES} else {store.open = NO};`

Have a look at [Apple's Date and Time Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html).

Comment: Problem is, then he has to recreate the open/close times regularly so the don't expire.

Answer (score 0):

Keep open dates as "0-11:00-open", 0-13:00-closed", "1-11:00-open", "1-18:00-closed", etc.  Sort the list.  Find the current day/time in the list.  Examine the adjacent entries to see if open or closed.

You can reduce the strings down to simple numbers (eg, 011000, 012001...) if you wish to have the slightly simpler/faster numeric sort/compare.

You do have to be a little careful at midnight (switch day # when you switch from 2359 to 0000 (don't use 2400)) and between Saturday and Sunday.

And of course it's always wise to do a "sanity check" -- check that opens and closes alternate.

Comment: I agree with your comment on @Mike Z's answer, but how would this translate to data management? Wether I am storing this in a database or just plist file, this looks to get unmanageable quickly.

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL doesn't support true "before" and "after" queries (a major flaw, IMO), or it would be quite simple.  One could insert each time quantity in a table with the store ID as another field, query the store ID (and possibly day) and retrieve the values sorted, then walk through them.  Or one could insert all the times as a string (JSON or simple string -- already sorted) in the main store record, retrieve and parse the string, then walk through it.  I'd probably go with the simple string -- just walk through it N characters at a time, since the values are fixed-length.

Comment: "Walk through it" - too much room for human input error. There has to be something more robust and generic than this.

Comment: @JoeMasilotti -- "Walk through it" means to step sequentially through the list and compare, in a simple loop.  If the list is arranged as fixed-length entries (pre-processed as I described above) this is fairly efficient and reasonably robust. (You should verify the format and general "goodness" of the data before you put it into the DB.)